# Cannot map project with svn provider (subclipse) on Eclipse Luna

Tags: svn, eclipse-luna

Getting this error with File->New->Project:

> cannot map project with svn provider

In Eclipse console, the following message is found

```
Malformed network data svn: Unable to parse URL '/svn/mytech/!svn/bc/3457/trunk/ReadyAPI Keys/'
```

When I checked out the project using Tortoise SVN from the command line it worked. This is not what I wanted. I want SVN to work from within Eclipse.

Any clues why I'm getting the error?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to be a lot more specific as to what you've already tried and when do you get the error.

Comment: Updated. I am still unable to check out  SVN project into Eclipse.

Comment: Problem resolved. Tried a different  url  http://svn.mydev.org/svn/mytech/trunk/code instead of http://svn.mydev.org/svn/mytech/trunk

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with eclipse luna and svn 1.8.

First, I closed out eclipse, then I deleted the original project files that had already been checked out previously.  I then brought up eclipse using the -clean startup option.  For my path on my machine it was: C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean on my shortcut in Windows 7.

I did get a warning from eclipse that the old project was still there, even though it wasn't and it would overwrite the old project, so I opted to do that.  It checked out fine.